# Is there any way to access media Folder in iPhone , iPad

Tags: iphone

For my app, i need to access Media folder, 
Is it possible, if yes it would be great if someone can share one sample code

Answer (score 0):

With Following guide, you can access iPod media

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Also for images,

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html